# Android, Why I can set the same key in one strings.xml and no compile errors?

Tags: android

like this,I don't know what happened, I cleaned my project and build many times and refresh, but no compile errors, is ant's bug?

values-fr/strings.xml

```
<string name="hello">a</string>

<string name="hello">b</string>
```

Comment: Would be nice to get an error message here, yes...

Comment: Why there are unclear close votes on this question? This question looks clear enough to me..

Answer (score 1):

It is not a compile time error. I could not find any reference for this. But in my opinion this line

`<string name="hello">a</string>`

will creates a id in `gen` folder with name `hello`. So when you redefine this in next line. It checks for the same `name` found it and did not create it again.

So if you want to check the duplicates keys. You can run

```
Android Tools > Run Lint : Check for Common Errors
```